# Как 2х мерный массив конвертировать в 3х мерный массив в консоли

Tags: c#

Имеется 2х мерный массив с данными эти данные нужно перекинуть в 3х мерный массив и вывести на экран.
Как это реализовать до этого времени с 3х мерными матрицами не сталкивлся?

```
int[,] 2darray = new int[5, 4] = {{1,2,3,4,5}{5,4,3,2,1}{6,7,8,9,0}{0,9,8,7,6}{1,3,5,7,9}}
```

Comment: Как вы хотите представить ваш массив?

Comment: что значит представить? вывод в консоли

Comment: какой массив должен получиться, если на вход подать ваш `2darray`

Comment: Как трёхмерный массив должен выглядеть на экране? Покажите желаемый вывод целиком.

Comment: Его значение нужно просто вывести и все,

Answer (score 0):

Инициализация трехмерной матрицы:

```
  int[, ,] array3Da = new int[2, 2, 3] { { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } },{ { 7, 8, 9 }, { 10, 11, 12 } } };
```

Доступ к элементу:

```
System.Console.WriteLine(array3Da[1, 0, 1]);
```